# How to use proxy internet in windows for Desktop apps like skype, whatsApp

Tags: proxy, localhost, skype, http-proxy, ssh-tunnel

Here I am doing local port forwarding using SSH tunneling to my college server

by using ssh -L port:proxy:port username@ip

then i am using internet using proxy as localhost and port, if i set proxy as localhost and port in browser it is working fine.

but now my question is can we use that proxy internet to skype, whatsApp like Desktop Apps ?

**Note** : This proxy contains authentication also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those apps are using the proxy set in Internet Explorer by default, if you set one, they should use it automatically. For some apps you can as well set a specific proxy that won't use the one set in IE.

Comment: I have already did it, What about skype ?  does it use IE Proxy ??

Comment: Yes Skype uses IE proxy, did you set it up the way it works with for your browser?

Comment: yes, i set proxy in IE, and for Skype we need to set proxy in Skype also.

Comment: Same issue, I'm trying to use WhatsAPP over proxy as I'm in China mainland, but it is not workable even if I set proxy in IE. What should I do? My system is Windows 11.